# Firebase log event together with parameters

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to log an event with parameters in Firebase. I can send the event, and it appears in my dashboard after 24H [~4K users], but I can not see the parameters in the details, or using them to create new audiences.

1. I launch the event "A" together with some variables:

```swift
    Analytics.logEvent("survey_submit", parameters: [
       "survey_option_a": true,
       "survey_option_b": false,
       "survey_option_c": true,
       "survey_option_d": true,
       "survey_option_others": false,
    ])
```

2. I have registered the parameters in Firebase using **Custom Definitions**
3. I tried to create a new audience using the event `survey_submit` and any of the parameters. I can not see the parameters in the details of the event.

Any help is more than welcomed :)

Environment:

- Firebase 7.10.0
- iOS SDK.